# Write large dask dataframe into a single S3 CSV file

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I'm working with a dask.distributed cluster and I'd like to save a large dataframe to a single CSV file to S3, keeping the order of partitions if possible (by default to_csv() writes dataframe to multiple files, one per partition). Moreover, this file storage operation should also be performed as a lazy/delayed task (it should be executed on a cluster worker).

First solution that I can think of is storing the partitions in a temporary S3 location and then use S3 multipart upload in a delayed function to merge/upload these files together. The temporary storage is a disadvantage here.

Can it be done using dataframe.to_delayed()? Upload needs to be performed by a single delayed function (S3 doesn't have append operation), at the same time the dataframe may be larger than worker's memory, so the function cannot simply depend on all dataframe partitions.

PS. CSV format is the requirement for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could certainly use `df.map_partitions` to write to several files, and then `s3fs`'s [`merge`](http://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem.merge) method to create a single final file (remembering that all but the first piece should not write a header line).

You could also use `to_delayed` to do a similar thing, as you suggest. You would need to [create](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/blob/master/s3fs/core.py#L1147) the multi-part upload, pass it along with each delayed object to your uploader, and collect the pieces in a delayed [finalize](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/blob/master/s3fs/core.py#L1189) step - links are to code in s3fs that does something similar.

Comment: Ok, I had similar idea, but I'm not sure about the "pass along" part, I'd have to upload each partition in a separate delayed function call and each one of them could be potentially executed on a different worker. I'll go over that code and try something along these lines.

Comment: by "pass long", I mean that the your upload function will be like `f(mpu, data)` where `data` is one of the delayed parts (different for each invocation) and `mpu` is the handle you create in the same way as in s3fs (same for all calls).

Comment: To follow up, right, that was my idea too, I ended up using a chain of delayed functions to pass along partitions until they are merged into big enough piece to be added to multipart upload. Saving files and merging them afterwards proved not to be any simpler because s3fs API also requires chunks of min. 5MB, so in general case some kind of partition aggregation would be needed.